# lmer model - accessing elements of the model

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am an R beginner and even newer to lmer and mixed effects modelling.

If I have an lmer model of:

```
model <- lmer(C ~ Group * Time + (1|ID), REML = FALSE, data=data)
```

How do I access details of the model in order to plot them?

I know I can plot the residuals against the fitted values using either:

```
plot(model)
```

OR

```
plot(predict(model), resid(model))
```

But is there a way to access other elements/details of the model? What other model elements can be accessed? I am aware that I can use the function 'summary()' to look up the random and fixed effect. But what about plotting the residuals against other elements of the model e.g. residuals against fixed effects or random effect?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What details do you want specifically?

Comment: Hi MrFlick. Basically, my 'Time' fixed effect in my model is a factor of 7 levels. My residual vs fitted plot looks a bit strange so I would like to plot my residuals against my 'Time' factor in its 7 levels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have doubts like this you shoud check the Vignette of the package, in this case `vignette(lme4)`. Only with a superficial search I found this table that maybe is of use:

| Method | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `anova` | Decomposition of fixed-effects contributions or model comparison. |
| `as.function` | Function returning profiled deviance or REML criterion. |
| `coef` | Sum of the random and fixed effects for each level. |
| `confint` | Confidence intervals on linear mixed-model parameters. |
| `deviance` | Minus twice maximum log-likelihood. (Use `REMLcrit` for the REML criterion.) |
| `df.residual` | Residual degrees of freedom. |
| `drop1` | Drop allowable single terms from the model. |
| `extractAIC` | Generalized Akaike information criterion |
| `fitted` | Fitted values given conditional modes. |
| `fixef` | Estimates of the fixed-effects coefficients |
| `formula` | Mixed-model formula of fitted model. |
| `logLik` | Maximum log-likelihood. |
| `model.frame` | Data required to fit the model. |
| `model.matrix` | Fixed-effects model matrix |
| `ngrps` | Number of levels in each grouping factor. |
| `nobs` | Number of observations. |
| `plot` | Diagnostic plots for mixed-model fits. |
| `predict` | Various types of predicted values. |
| `print` | Basic printout of mixed-model objects. |
| `profile` | Profiled likelihood over various model parameters. |
| `ranef` | Conditional modes of the random effects. |
| `refit` | A model (re)fitted to a new set of observations of the response variable. |
| `refitML` | A model (re)fitted by maximum likelihood. |
| `residuals` | Various types of residual values. |
| `sigma` | Residual standard deviation. |
| `simulate` | Simulated data from a fitted mixed model. |
| `summary` | Summary of a mixed model. |
| `terms` | Terms representation of a mixed model. |
| `update` | An updated model using a revised formula or other arguments. |
| `VarCorr` | Estimated random-effects variances, standard deviations, and correlations. |
| `vcov` | Covariance matrix of the fixed-effect estimates. |
| `weights` | Prior weights used in model fitting. |

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to plot residuals vs your time factor:

```r
library(broom.mixed)
aa <- augment(model)
boxplot(.resid ~ Time, data = aa)
```

You could also use the built-in plot method (see `help("plot.merMod")`):

```r
plot(model, resid(.) ~ Time)
```

Comment: I had to convert my Time factor to numeric but this worked! Thank you!

Comment: if it was useful you can upvote it ...

Comment: I marked it as the answer but since I am a new user, I can't upvote yet

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `summary()` function just like with any other `lm` or `glm` object to get an assessment of the actual model.

Similarly you can treat these objects like you would a dataframe.

The only difference is instead of using the `$` you should use the `@` symbol.

For example:

```
lm <- lmer(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width + (1|Species), data = iris)

lm@frame %>% head()

 Petal.Length Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species
1          1.4          5.1         3.5  setosa
2          1.4          4.9         3.0  setosa
3          1.3          4.7         3.2  setosa
4          1.5          4.6         3.1  setosa
5          1.4          5.0         3.6  setosa
6          1.7          5.4         3.9  setosa
```

You can from that point explore deeper in the object.

Comment: I don't recommend this - elements of S4 objects (accessed via `@`) are generally intended to be used by developers rather than end-users. Accessor functions like `model.frame()` are better (see  Míriam Muñoz Lapeira's answer)

Comment: Good point, I learned something new! Though in defence on this, sometimes accessing elements is an extremely powerful way of understanding how a model is working. Probably not super relevant to a beginner who is trying to plot some residuals, but useful nonetheless.