# How to display more decimals in estimates from lmer() function in R-package lmerTest?

Tags: r, decimal, digits, lmertest

I want to test fixed and random effects with the lmerTest R-package. After defining the model with lmer(), I use summary() to get the results. For my results report, I would like to display more decimals of AIC and BIC, of Variance and Std.Dev in Random Effects, of the Estimate and Std.Error (see picture:
[my output summary(lmer) with missing/few decimals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i8a6.png) ).

Things I have already tried out that do not help:

1. changing general R options

```
options(digits=3)
```

2. changing options within summary() or coef(summary())

```
summary(lmer, digits=3)
coef(summary(lmer), digits=3)
```

3. using round() for summary() or coef(summary())

```
round(summary(lmer), digits=3)
round(coef(summary(lmer)), digits=3)
```

4. searching the terms "digit" and "decimal" in the lmerTest R-package manual

Comment: Can you please post your results as text rather than as a link to an image?  (You can cut-and-paste text into a code block delimited by triple-backticks ``` )

Comment: One other way to approach this is to inspect the object/ list `lmer`, you can do so by `str(lmer)`. It should be a list with lists containing the underlying data, model parameters, and various fit statistics.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to load the `jtools` package and use `options( "jtools-digits" = 3 )`. When calling your model results, use the `summ` function to view them.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work (even when adding the " that were missing in your code). The output still only has two decimals for each value.

Answer (score 1):

At present it's not possible to adjust the digit setting for the printing of AIC etc.. You can hack this a bit by using the internal function:

```r
lme4:::.prt.aictab(summary(model)$AICtab, digits = 10)
         AIC          BIC       logLik     deviance     df.resid 
1763.9393445 1783.0970856 -875.9696722 1751.9393445          174
```

The global `digits` option should affect the printing of `coef(summary(.))`:

```r
options(digits = 10)
coef(summary(model))
                Estimate  Std. Error          df      t value        Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 251.40510485 6.632122742 18.00113477 37.907185169 1.263751938e-18
```

and of the random effects variances:

```r
VarCorr(model)
Groups   Name        Std.Dev.   Corr    
 Subject  (Intercept) 23.7797596         
          Days         5.7167985 0.081321
 Residual             25.5919070
```

For extracting components of a mixed model, also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76035709/lmer-model-accessing-elements-of-the-model/) and the `glance()` and `tidy()` functions from the `broom.mixed` package.

Comment: For the decimals of AIC and BIC, `lme4:::.prt.aictab(ss$AICtab, digits = 10)` does not work, it says the $ operator not defined for this S4 class. I found `extractAIC(ss)` for AIC, but still do not know how to get more decimals for the BIC. `options(digits = 10); coef(summary(mm))` for Variance and `VarCorr(mm)` for Std.Dev in Random Effects and `of the Estimate and Std.Error worked, many thanks!

Comment: Note that `ss` is not the original model, but a `summary()` of it. I've updated my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

```
emm_options(opt.digits = FALSE)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.